# Wiring pull switch ceiling fan to wall switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

This is a slightly different question to one previously asked on this site (see: [Changing a pull switch to a hard wired wall switch Ceiling fans](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/79818/changing-a-pull-switch-to-a-hard-wired-wall-switch-ceiling-fans#)).

I would like to wire a ceiling fan with light that is currently pull switch controlled for both the fan and the light. The line running to the fan is on a 15 amp breaker, so I need to use 14 awg wire. Ideally, for the reasons one of the administrators of this site stated in the question I cited above, I would like to use 14/4 awg wire, but I cannot find any electrical house or hardware store that sells 14/4 wire in any length other than a spool of 250 feet. Not needing that size, I have decided to switch to 14-2-2 with ground and do the job that way. I just wanted to confirm that I can use 14-2-2 just as I would the 14/4 (obviously with the exception of the color difference in the wires) wire.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 14-2-2, no problem. Realistically, you could use 14-3. You will not draw enough current to pose a problem. Same holds for wiring both the fan and light together and using 14-2. That being said, some localities do not allow the use of 14-3 in residential.